# How to return first value of a query string, if it has multiple values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Consider a url like this :

```
http://host.com?q=1&o=2&q=1
```

---

If i run `Request.QueryString["q"]`, I get the value twice.

If I run `Request.QueryString["q"].FirstOrDefault().ToString()` I seem to get "2"

How to return first value of a query string, if it has multiple values?

Comment: should that be another `&` at the end?

Comment: you have to split values Request.QueryString["q"].ToString().Split(',').FirstOrDefault().ToString()

Comment: why you have to use same parameter names?

Comment: @NiMA sometimes these things are beyond your control

Comment: @NiMa that's the format I receive from a Cisco API, nothing I can do about that :)

Comment: I've just tested this and your code worked fine for me? If I use `Request.QueryString["q"].FirstOrDefault().ToString()` I get the first value of q

Comment: up 1,I'm here to learn :)

Comment: Do you want the 'first' one, or a 'specific' one? How can you handle the data not knowing what you get?

Comment: how could you use `FirstOrDefault` on an NameValueCollection which is not an `IENumerable<T>` ?

Comment: @Selman22 - Because `NameValueCollection` inherits from `NameObjectCollectionBase` which implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @NiMa There are a few ways this can happen, but usually it comes from a `<select multiple>` or a list of related checkboxes with the same `name`, e.g. in a survey "What do you have for breakfast - tick one or more options"

Comment: @NiMa We can have same name query string multiple times Like /page.aspx?ProductID=1&ProductID=15&ProductID=25

Comment: @RahulSingh so what is your point

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting `2` from your second snippet.

Comment: I just assumed it returned the count of values for the query string

Comment: @Selman22 - You said "How could you use FirstOrDefault.." So in that context I said, he can since it implements `IEnumebrable`.

Comment: There is no FirstOrDefault method on IENumerable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how microsoft handle this thing, what i can see is if we pass same key with multiple values then .NET framework treat values as comma seperated string,

i.e.

if query is like **"?q=10&o=2&q=11"**

then

```
Request.QueryString["q"] == "10,11"
```

the only way to get first value is splitting up against comma.

```
Request.QueryString["q"].Split(',')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of someone has the same question.
Try this: `Request.QueryString.GetValues("q")?.FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var count=0;
var twince=string.Empty;
foreach(var item in Request.QueryString["q"])
{
     twince=item;
     count++;
     if(count==2)
        break;
}
```

OR

```
var twince=Request.QueryString["q"].Split(',')[1];
```

OR

```
var first=QueryString["q"].FirstOrDefault;
var twince=Request.QueryString["q"].FirstOrDefault(frs=>frs!=first);
```